# Regex to validate this format

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to validate a specific format. Here is it:

`key=0(or)1;key=0(or)1;(repeated-or-not);key=0(or)1.`

Or said otherwise:

1. \w
2. sign
3. 0 or 1
4. ; sign only between elements. Not on the last element.
5. All of previous repeated, or not.

The specificity is that the string **can not** end with a ";".

For now I've this `^(?:[a-z]+=[01];?)+(?<!;)$` which is right but not completely. since `foo=1;bar=0foo=0;bar=1`passes but even tough this part `bar=0foo=0`is incorrect.

Here are my current regex and some testing strings: https://regex101.com/r/lX0xT7/1

Thank you for your help,
Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\w+=[01](?:;\w+=[01])*$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX0xT7/2)

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your original regex-

```
^(?:[a-z]+=[01];)*(?:[a-z]+=[01])$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX0xT7/3)

Comment: Also a valid answer. I don't select it as "correct" in order to preserve the [a-z] part. Thank you!